# Provide passphrase to plymouth ask-for-password from command line

Tags: ssh, boot, luks

I'm working on booting a headless server (Fedora 16), entering the passphrase to decrypt the root disk (LUKS) over SSH using dropbear. I've got dropbear all working: I can SSH to the server while it's sitting and waiting for the password. But I can't figure out how to actually pass the password to use.

The crypt script that asks for the password and decrypts the volume uses the `plymouth ask-for-password` command; is there a way to pass the password into this command from the command line? I've tried writing to the process's stdin, but that didn't work. Is there some other way I can do it?

Comment: I don't know plymouth (or even dropbear) but programs which prompts for a password typically do not read stdin.  The program "expect" can "supply" a password to password prompts.  Additionally I've noticed a tendency lately for more and more programs that prompt for a password supply an option to make them read from the command-line, or a file, or a password specified with the command arguments.

Comment: I thought plymouth was something for graphical boot only. So for SSH that'd be barking up the wrong tree. Not sure. `cryptsetup` itself is happy to receive passwords in any number of ways (pipe, file, prompt)

Comment: Yes, plymouth is used for graphical boot, but it's also used by the dracut crypto module to ask for your password when decrypting the root filesystem at boot. I'm working on setting up a headless server that I can unlock remotely over SSH, so I'm looking for a way to give the password to the plymouth from the SSH CLI.

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly: / is encrypted; however, you can log in through SSH? Now, what you're wanting is a way to unlock / from SSH?

Comment: @SailorCire: That's right. I have dropbear running from the initramfs (i.e., `/boot`), so it's able to run before `/` is unlocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a kind of hacky work around, but it is working for me, and I've been using it for several months now. It basically just replaces the `cryptroot-ask` shell script with a custom one that waits for you to SSH in, unlock the disk yourself, and then delete a file to indicate that it's gone. Replacement of the `cryptroot-ask` script is done based on a option passed to the kernel, so you can easily disable it from your GRUB, or your bootloader of choice.

It's all available from: https://bitbucket.org/bmearns/dracut-crypt-wait

Answer (score 1):

You would need to rewrite or replace the script in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/cryptroot`

Comment: Could you elaborate on that a bit? What would have to be replaced?